# Can I position angular material components by code?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am trying develop a responsive angular app.

Is it possible to set height, set position to angular material `<mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>` component by code without css?

I had tried with css, its not working as expected.

eg. in javascript

```
const box = document.getElementById('box');
box.style.position = 'absolute';
box.style.top = '150px';
box.style.left = '150px';
```

I want to set height of `<mat-sidenav>` and `<mat-sidenav-content>` dynamically on pageload.

**I am expecting this layout.**

[image]

**But my current layout is**

[image]

Here is my code

```
<header>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button (click)="snav.toggle()" mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span>My App</span>
        <span class="mat-toolbar-spacer"></span>
        <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item>
                <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
                <span>Redial</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-menu-item disabled>
                <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
                <span>Check voice mail</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-menu-item>
                <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
                <span>Disable alerts</span>
            </button>
        </mat-menu>
    </mat-toolbar>
</header>

<mat-sidenav-container class="mat-sidenav-container" [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [opened] = "!mobileQuery.matches" [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'" [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches"
        fixedTopGap="56">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content #matSidenavContent >
        <p *ngFor="let content of fillerContent">{{content}}</p>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>



.mat-toolbar-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
}

footer {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

mat-sidenav-container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

mat-sidenav{
    margin-top: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

mat-sidenav-content{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    /*height:520px;*/ /* i don't want to set it here */
    height:100%;
}

mat-nav-list{
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
}

mat-nav-list mat-list-item{
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    mat-nav-list{
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: auto;
    }

    mat-sidenav{
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    mat-sidenav-content{
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        height:auto;
    }
    
    footer {
        position:initial;
        left:initial;
        bottom: initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz ?

Comment: Okay sure, will create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've created a stackblitz that demonstrates how you can use css's `flex box` to arrange your components.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-ibb7yj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

In `styles.css`, make sure you set your body and html:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then your `app.component.html` can look something like this:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>My App</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-drawer-container class="container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>
     Side Nav stuff here!
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <div class="content">
      main content here!
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer stuff here!
    </div>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Lastly, some extra CSS to arrange the components:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

mat-drawer-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

mat-drawer {
  width: 20%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

mat-drawer-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90px; //some fixed height for your footer

  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: It is working as expected. Thank you very much